# why the Image is not displayed in Grid view?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imagepath") %>' Height="100px"
                   Width="100px" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The path which is binding is `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Image/FolderName/abc.jpg` from a table, but it is not getting displayed. The image is in the same folder and it is not even giving any exception.

Comment: you can not give imagepath like that and have to change it like `~/Image/FolderName/abc.jpg`

Comment: but the image is not present in my application folder.It is outside it

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20782/Displaying-Images-from-a-Database-in-a-GridView

Comment: Not working. any other suggesstions?

Comment: Can you send us original path of `imagepath` column from your database? I mean where is it coming from?

Comment: @Pwavel002 you will not be able to display image with that path. Either you have to add it to your application folder or you can create httphandler or can use this [article](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Displaying-images-that-are-stored-outside-the-Website-Root-Folder.aspx)

Comment: Image is coming from C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Image/FolderName/abc.jpg and is stored in database table

Comment: One way to diagnose this is the F12/developer tools in your browser. Watch the Network panel to see what path the browser is requesting and what the server is returning. I suspect, like @Sandeep, that the URL to the image you're building does not match where the image is hosted on the server. If it's not in the application folder, but is accessible from the root of the web server, then /Image/FolderName/abc.jpg should work.

Comment: Also, is this a homework assignment that some folks started today? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002891/image-is-not-showing-up-in-listview-from-database-visual-studio-asp-net

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src='<%# Eval("imagepath").ToString() %>' Width="100px" Height="100">
```

maybe you can do something like that??

Answer (score 0):

this codes are gridview's source

```
<asp:GridView ID="grv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
             <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PicID" HeaderText="PicID" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="PicID"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PicURL" HeaderText="PicURL" SortExpression="PicURL"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PicName" HeaderText="PicName" SortExpression="PicName"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date"></asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Picutre ID" DataField="PicID"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="PicName"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Added" DataField="Date" DataFormatString="{0:d}"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="PicURL" ></asp:ImageField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

this codes are sql table

```
CREATE TABLE PicTable
(
PicID int identity(1,1),
PicURL nvarchar(50),
PicName nvarchar(50),
Date datetime
);


select * from PicTable
insert PicTable values('~/Uploads/4626411630_ASO%20(1).jpg','Water Lilies','2015.02.27')
```

you can add values like that.
you have to have a folder in your solution explorer.
For example my folder name is Uploads.
I hope this codes are helpful for you or another developer

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead you can directly convert the BLOB or Binary in <asp:Image> tag and click on the Button Tag, it will take you to the IndexChangedFunction and you can do further operations with the grid:

    <asp:GridView ID="Gvid" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gvid_SelectedIndexChanged" >
            <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IMAGE" Visible="false">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image runat ="server"  ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("IMAGE")) %>' ID="Image"  />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:ButtonField DataTextField ="MODEL" CommandName="select" HeaderText ="MODEL" />
</Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```