# Image is not showing up in Listview from Database Visual Studio asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I a quite new to Visual Studio and .net. So I am basically trying to get an image to show up from a connected Database. I have all the information showing just not the image. Here is the code needed to see if anyone can correct the error. Its probably something simple but as I said I'm new to all this.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:photochunkConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [PhotoName], [Details], [Image], [UploadDate], [PhotoTypeID] FROM [Photos] ORDER BY [UploadDate]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <span style="">PhotoName:
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("PhotoName") %>' runat="server" ID="PhotoNameLabel" /><br />
            Details:
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Details") %>' runat="server" ID="DetailsLabel" /><br />
            Image:
            <asp:Image ImageURL='<%# Eval("Image") %>' runat="server" ID="ImageLabel" Width="200px" /><br />
            UploadDate:
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("UploadDate") %>' runat="server" ID="UploadDateLabel" /><br />
            PhotoTypeID:
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("PhotoTypeID") %>' runat="server" ID="PhotoTypeIDLabel" /><br />
            <br />
        </span>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Is "Image" a string i.e. a URL or the actual binary content of the image?

Comment: @JamesMcLachlan "Image" is the column name within the database

Comment: I mean what kind of data is the value in the database?